# how to set axios post parameters as object?

Tags: javascript, rest, axios

when the SMS is sent using the API in template literal way works smoothly:

```
axios.post(
     `https://api.fooserver.com/${API_KEY}/verify/lookup?receptor=${phone}&token=${code}`
    )
     .then(resp => resp.data)
```

whats wrong with the object param?

```
axios.post(`https://api.kavenegar.com/v1/${API_KEY}/verify/lookup`, {
            receptor: phone,
            token: code
        })
        .then(resp => resp.data);
```

it does send request but the object params.

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: the second form sends request but the object params are not sent

Comment: How do you know that params are not sent?

Comment: could you try my edited answer please

Comment: Just see: https://kavenegar.com/rest.html#sms-Lookup

Comment: Second arg of axios post method is body of request.

Comment: have seen that bro, I removed pattern param in the question to have a brief question, pay attention that template literal mode i have the same params and no err. @VahidAlimohamadi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucky I understood your question:), using params Axios will automaticity translate your object in query params.
Use this:

```
axios.post(`https://api.kavenegar.com/v1/${API_KEY}/verify/lookup`,{}, {
        params: {
            receptor: phone,
            token: code
        }})
        .then(resp => resp.data);
```

Comment: may I ask you to have a look at an `axios` related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59470085/vue-js-validation-fails-for-file-upload-in-axios-when-multipart-form-data-used ?

Comment: you have  some answers in there, tell me if none worked

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you are sending the data as query parameters, which isn't the same as sending it in the post body, as in the second example.

You *can* in fact pass your query parameters as an object, you just need to call `.post` a little differently:

```
axios
    .post(
        `https://api.fooserver.com/${API_KEY}/verify/lookup`,
        {},
        {
            params: {
                receptor: phone,
                token: code
            }
        }
        )
    .then(resp => resp.data);
```

Or, if you so desire:

```
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `https://api.fooserver.com/${API_KEY}/verify/lookup`,
    params: {
        receptor: phone,
        token: code
    }
})
.then(resp => resp.data);
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use `querystring.stringify`

Like this :

```
 const querystring = require('querystring');
    axios.post(`https://api.kavenegar.com/v1/${API_KEY}/verify/lookup`, querystring.stringify({
                receptor: phone,
                token: code
            })
            .then(resp => resp.data);
```