# Vue.js - validation fails for file upload in axios when multipart/form-data used in header

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios, bootstrap-vue, vee-validate

I am building a Laravel+Vue.js SPA (Single Page Application) with [BootstrapVue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/), [VeeValidate](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/forms.html#validate-before-submit) and  axios as the HTTP client.

Inside axios, when I use  `multipart/form-data; boundary=${uploadForm._boundary}` as the `Content-Type` in `headers` **then all the validations in Laravel Controller method fail**.

But if I use `'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'` in `header`  then validation works **except the `file` input field. The `file` field becomes empty in Laravel controller method.**

This  happens within the  component `EditProfile.vue`. The content there is :

```html
<template>
    <ValidationObserver ref="form" v-slot="{ passes }">

        <div id="registration_form">

            <div id="form_title" class="text-center">Edit Your Profile</div>
            <div v-html="result" class="result text-center"></div>

            <b-form name="uploadForm" @submit.prevent="passes(onSubmit)" @reset="resetForm"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <ValidationProvider vid="name" rules="required|min:2" name="name" v-slot="{ valid, errors }">
                    <b-form-group
                            label="User Name:"
                            label-for="exampleInput1"
                    >
                        <b-form-input
                                type="text"
                                disable-leading-trailing-space
                                v-model="name"
                                plaintext
                                :state="errors[0] ? false : (valid ? true : null)"
                                placeholder="Enter your name"
                        ></b-form-input>
                        <b-form-invalid-feedback id="inputLiveFeedback">{{ errors[0] }}</b-form-invalid-feedback>
                    </b-form-group>
                </ValidationProvider>


                <ValidationProvider vid="photo" rules="required" name="photo" v-slot="{ valid, errors }">
                    <b-form-group
                            label="Photo:"
                            label-for="exampleInput1"
                    >

                        <b-form-file
                            accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg"
                            v-model="file"
                            :state="Boolean(file)"
                            placeholder="Choose a file or drop it here..."
                            drop-placeholder="Drop file here..."
                            @change="onFileChange" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                        ></b-form-file>
                        <b-form-invalid-feedback id="inputLiveFeedback">{{ errors[0] }}</b-form-invalid-feedback>
                        <div class="mt-3">Selected file: {{ file ? file.name : '' }}</div>

                        <!-- Plain mode -->
                        <!--<b-form-file v-model="file2" class="mt-3" plain></b-form-file>
                        <div class="mt-3">Selected file: {{ file2 ? file2.name : '' }}</div>-->

                        <div id="preview">
                            <img v-if="url" :src="url" />
                        </div>

                    </b-form-group>
                </ValidationProvider>

                <b-button type="submit" variant="primary">Submit</b-button>
                <b-button type="reset" variant="danger">Reset</b-button>
            </b-form>

        </div><!-- end of id registration_form-->
    </ValidationObserver>
</template>
```

In JS part, I have :

```js
<script>

    import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider } from "vee-validate";

     export default {
        name: "EditProfile",
        props: {

        },

        components: {
            ValidationObserver,
            ValidationProvider
        },
        data: () => ({

            name: "",
            photo:"",
            file:"",
            url:"",  
            result:''

        }),

        methods: {
            onFileChange(e) {
                this.file = e.target.files[0];
                this.url = URL.createObjectURL(this.file);
            },

            onSubmit() {
                console.log("Form submitted yay!");

                this.result='<span class="wait">Please wait ...</span>';

                axios.post('/update_profile_now',
                    {
                       name: this.name,
                       photo:this.file

                    }, // the data to post
                    {

                        headers: {
      
                            //Accept: 'application/json',

                           'Content-Type':  `multipart/form-data; boundary=${uploadForm._boundary}`
                            
                        }

                    })
                    .then(response => {
      
                        if(response.data.success){

                            this.result='<span class="succes">Registration completed !!</span>';
                        } else {

                            this.$refs.form.setErrors(response.data.errors);

                            this.result='<span class="error">Invalid data !!</span>';
                        }

                    })
                    .catch(error => {

                        if(typeof error !=="undefined"){

                            console.log(error);
                        }

                    });

                //    .finally(() => this.loading = false)
            },
            resetForm() {
                this.name = "";
      
                this.result='';

                requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                    this.$refs.form.reset();
                });
            }
        }
    };

</script>
```

In corresponding Laravel controller method I have :

```js
public function update_profile_now(Request $request) 
{

    $rules = array(

        'name' => 'required | min:4',
        'photo'=> 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // Validate the input and return correct response
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Response::json(array(
            'success' => false,
            'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()

        ), 200); 
    }

    //file uploading code goes here 

    return Response::json(array('success' => true), 200);

}
```

What I want is the form with a `file` input inside it will be submitted and then a JSON response will be sent from the method after file upload and other works.

So what should be the correct header or do I need to adopt any other means ?

Comment: you're trying to post the `this.file` as a `json` payload but with a `multipart` MIME type.. I guess it doesn't work this way.. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43014086/6611700 and pass the `name` field also as a multipart field (and not `json`)

Comment: ' pass the name field also as a multipart field (and not json) ' - what do you mean ? How to do that ?

Comment: well, I'm assuming you need to use [`FormData#append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) for that..

Comment: let me try with that

Comment: you right, it seems to be.

Answer (score 2):

I guess using [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) would work.

Below some examples:

[How to post a file from a form with Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43013858/how-to-post-a-file-from-a-form-with-axios#43014086)
[axios post request to send form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630163/axios-post-request-to-send-form-data)

Answer (score -1):

I Recommend using `VeeValidation` for validating your form after submitting it.

Its really simple and sweetest validation methods.

You can install it from here. [VeeValidation Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vee-validate)